# ZendFramework 2 - how do you handle from controller the layout head body footers like in ZF1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-controller

How to do the following __construct section shown in ZF1 on the fly in  ZF2 way?

I have tried `$this->headTitle('..');` by ommiting ->view call, but it still fail by throwing:

`Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for headTitle`

```
  public function __construct() { //init is gone 

    $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('brand');
    $this->HeadTitle($this->title)->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', $this->keyword)->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('description', $this->description)->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('Language', 'en')->setIndent(8);

    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('dc.title', $this->title)->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('dc.keywords', $this->keyword)->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('dc.description', $this->description)->setIndent(8);

    $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css')->setIndent(8);
    $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/jquery/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-
1.8.20.custom.css')->setIndent(8);

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $get = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could access to 'renderer' object in your action controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
    $renderer->headTitle('My title');

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But why it does not work in __construct method? Or lets say from preDispatch methods?

Comment: Maybe you can use it onBootstrap() within class module. See final example on http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/modules-in-zf2/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question and I have developed an ZF2 plugin to use headTitle like in layout.phtml file.
https://github.com/remithomas/rt-headtitle

```
public function indexAction(){
  $this->headTitle("My website")->setSeparator(" - ")->append("easy ?!");
  return new ViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to handle it for all actions in a controller

```
protected function setHeadTitle($title = ''){
    if(!empty($title)){            
        $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
        $renderer->headTitle($title);
    }
}
```

Use the function in your action

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $this->setHeadTitle("Login");
    //write some other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a plugin for all module

```
class HeadTitlePlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{

    public function setHeadTitle($title = '')
    {
        if (! empty($title)) {
            $renderer = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->
                              get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
            $renderer->headTitle($title);
        }
    }
}
```

Attach the plugin in module config

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'HeadTitlePlugin' => 'Modulename\Controller\Plugin\HeadTitlePlugin'
    )
),
```

Call the plugin function in controller action

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->HeadTitlePlugin()->setHeadTitle("Signup");
    // other codes 
}
```

Thats all